# How can I install nodejs modules to appfog

Tags: node.js, module, appfog

Normally in local, I use cmd, command line to install any nodejs module using "npm install testing or connect or etc.."
But I decided to use appfog as server and I add nodejs to my project on appfg but probably I am gonna need some nodejs modules like testing, connect, request etc..

The problem is I couldnt found tool like cmd on appfog or any way to add nodejs modules.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you just need to install the dependencies in your local environment and everything should be just fine. Simply specify all of your dependencies in your `package.json` file, run a typical `npm install`, and if the modules are properly installed in your local environment then they will be pushed to AppFog when you run `af update`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to develop your application on your local machine with all the required **dependencies** in the **json package** and **modules** in the **Node.JS**. And if your application is working properly at that time on your local machine then you can push all that application data to the AppFog using command line interface. Simply use the command `af  update <your app name>` Then start the application and you will see that everything is working properly.